# have separate js objects in a webpack project which interact with same variable

Tags: javascript, oop, webpack

I wanted to know if it was possible by combining webpack and js' oop to arrive at a functional code like the one presented below.
The goal is to be able to isolate each of the elements of my site (sidebar, main,...) in different files while making sure that they can interact between.

Is this possible with webpack and pure js or not?

```
import ApplePicker from "./my_path/applePicker.js";
import NiceFarmer from "./my_path/niceFarmer.js";

const orchard = function () {
    const appleNumber = 10;

    const jack = new ApplePicker();
    const daniel = new NiceFarmer();

    jack.eatAnApple();
    daniel.eatAnApple();

    // appleNumber have to be now === 2

}

// Example of applePicker.js structure

const ApplePicker = function () {

    this.eatAnApple = function () {
        // Do something
    }

}

export default ApplePicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

If you simply want to consume a variable from `applePicker.js`:

```
// applePicker.js
export const apples = 10
```

If you want to be able to reassign that variable you might want to add a simple facade layer on top of that:

```
// applePicker.js
let apple = 5

export function getApple() {
   return apple;
}

export function setApple(newValue) {
   apple = newValue;
}
```

Even better, if you want other functions to "fire" when a variable is changed, use the [Observer pattern](https://medium.com/@patrickackerman/the-observer-pattern-with-vanilla-javascript-8f85ea05eaa8)